# Windows 10 USB device disconnecting after a power failure

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, power-supply, power

My USB mouse is always getting disconnected after a power failure. I tried unplugging the device and plugging it again, the laser lights for sometime and then it stops. For all USB root hubs i had unchecked "Allow computer to turn off this device to save power" under power management. Nothing seems to solve this problem. When this happens i'm required to restart my laptop in order to get it in working condition.

Comment: "My USB mouse is always getting disconnected after a power surge" Buy a surge protector. "When this happens i'm required to restart my laptop in order to get it in working condition. " Buy a surge protector.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm using a surge protector. This issue happens when power goes off and comes back quickly.

Comment: "This issue happens when power goes off and comes back quickly" So replace your surge protector with a UPS

Comment: @DavidPostill But when i plug it again, the laser light stays for sometime and then it's turns of automatically. I don't think changing my power source to UPS will solve this problem. Anyway i will give it a try and update you.